# Python - Path/Folder/File creation

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system

I am running the following block of code to create the path to a new file:

```
# Opens/create the file that will be created
device_name = target_device["host"].split('.')

path = "/home/user/test_scripts/configs/" + device_name[-1] + "/"
print(path)

# Check if path exists
if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.makedirs(path)

# file = open(time_now + "_" + target_device["host"] + "_config.txt", "w")
file = open(path + time_now + "_" + device_name[0] + "_config.txt", "w")

# Time Stamp File
file.write('\n Create on ' + now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") +
           ' at ' + now.strftime("%H:%M:%S") + ' GMT\n')

# Writes output to file
file.write(output)

# Close file
file.close()
```

The code run as intended with the exception that it creates and saves the files on the directory:  /home/user/test_scripts/**configs/** instead on the indented one that should be: /home/user/test_scripts/configs/**device_name[-1]/**.

Please advise.

Regards,

./daq

Comment: How about you first `print(device_name[-1])` and then `print(path)` to see if the path is formed correctly before any other operations are performed?

Comment: The operation is perform correctly.  It creates the file and the directory is supposed to create, the only problem is that it places the file on the directory before the one it is supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `os.path.join(base_path, new_path)` [[Reference]](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) instead of string concatenation. For example:

```
path = os.path.join("/home/user/test_scripts/configs/", device_name[-1])
os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)

new_name = time_now + "_" + device_name[0] + "_config.txt"
with open(os.path.join(path, new_name), "w+") as file:
    file.write("something")
```

Although I don't get why you're creating a directory with device_name[**-1**] and as a file name using device_name[**0**].

Comment: Devices have unique names in our environment and they look something like this:

DeviceName.DeviceType.MiscDesription.Location

The folder being created (or tested if it exist) correspond to the location name.

Comment: Okay, hope the answer helps